# Export 2 gridviews which are placed side by side and images to pdf using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in asp.net, have two gridviews which are placed near each other, There are images which are acting as borders on the side of the Grid. Please can you help if this grids and the side images can be exported to pdf in asp.net?

[image: Image of the webpage]

Comment: You'll likely need a 3rd party lib to do anything like and will probably need to recreate the layout with whatever API you find. Or you could just use a browser like Chrome and Print to a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp can help you.

Put your grids and image inside an panel.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGrids" runat="server">
      <<YourGrids and Border Image >>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnExportAsPDF" runat="server" OnClick="btnExportAsPDF_Click">
```

In code behind

```
using System.Data;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

protected void btnExportAsPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    pnlGrids.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();     
}
```

Hope this helps to move you on. Don't forget to accept as answer if it helps!

Comment: I have used the above code, but when exporting the panel to pdf the alignment of the grids and images is disturbed.

Comment: You can fix by debuging "pnlGrids" contents and try to edit your HTML classes /height/width or change Document page size.

Comment: I tried the above code but when exporting it first exports the images then the 1st grid and then the 2nd one under other.